# How to solve - ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Tags: python, floating-point, text-files

```
training_age_in = [1, 2, 3]

training_salary_dep = [5, 9, 10]

m = [(training_age_in[0], training_salary_dep[0]), (training_age_in[1], training_salary_dep[1]),
     (training_age_in[2], training_salary_dep[2])]

intercept_value = open("intercept_value", "r+")

slope_value = open("slope_value", "r+")

input_place = open("input_place", "r+")

intercept = float(intercept_value.read())

slope = float(slope_value.read())

input_place.seek(1)

input_place.write(str(training_age_in[0]))

number0 = float(input_place.read())

predicted_Y0 = intercept + (slope * number0)

error0 = (training_salary_dep[0] - predicted_Y0) ** 2
print(number0)
```

That's my code and it keeps coming up with a
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''. How could I solve this.

Comment: `input_place.truncate()` followed by `input_place.read()`? What do you hope to read after you truncated the file?

Comment: Does truncating the file delete whatever's in the file? If it does then it wasn't working for me since when I truncated it, the string was still in there.

Comment: You don't show the trace output so we can't be sure exactly which line the error is occurring on. However, it's clear that one (or maybe more) of the file read() functions is returning something that cannot be interpreted as a float. Try printing the read() response before trying to convert it. Also, consider closing your files

Comment: What is in the file 'input_place' when you first run this code? It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve